# Anagram generator for Windows and Linux

Tags: windows, linux, offline

I need an offline application that can get all the words in a particular word given.

(An example of what I need is [Wordles](http://www.wordles.com/getwordsinwords.aspx) but it should be offline.)

Example : If I enter `Today`, I will get

> A,
>   AD,
>   ADO,
>   AT,
>   AY,
>   DAY,
>   DO,
>   DOT,
>   OAT,
>   OD,
>   TA,
>   TAD,
>   TO,
>   TOAD,
>   TOADY,
>   TOD,
>   TODAY,
>   TODY,
>   TOY,
>   YOD,

The application should be for Linux and Windows.

Comment: For English only?

Comment: Does it require interchangeable dictionaries. Also, does it have to be precompiled, or can cross-platform be achieved by downloading the source code instead?

Answer (score 6):

### `an`

"`an`" is a open source text-based anagram generator originally from around 1996. The original author is no longer reachable, but since it was released as [GPL](https://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html) it still gets patches if they are ever needed (). However there at least two sites still "maintaining" the software, [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man6/an.6.html), [here](http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/a/an/) and [here](http://fatphil.org/words/an.html).

From the `manpage`:

> NAME
>          an - Anagram generator
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          an  [-w] [-c string] [-d dictionary] [-l number_words] [-m word_length]
>          [-u string] [-n number_anagrams] [--words] [--contain  string]  [--dict
>          dictionary]  [--length  number_words]  [--minimum word_length]  [--used
>          string] [--number number_anagrams] [--help] [--version] PHRASE
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          an finds all anagrams which can be made from  the  letters  in  PHRASE,
>          using        words        in       the       specified       dictionary
>          (default=/usr/share/dict/words).

- Linux:

  - On Linux distros that are based on [Debian](http://www.debian.org/) (such as Ubuntu or
    [LinuxMint](http://www.linuxmint.com/)):

    `sudo apt-get install an`
  - Otherwise download, compile and install the tar from one of the two sites listed above.
- Windows:

  - It is likely that only recompiling is needed to generate the win32 / win64 binaries due to the low resource requirements of the program. [This](http://fatphil.org/words/an.html) website claims to have have built a win32 binary or at least a windows targeted makefile, [here](http://fatphil.org/words/an-0.95-4_winfiles.tgz), although I have not tried it.

I was actually using `an` the other day. It can produce a large list if there are a lot of letters, so I recommend using `more` or `less` to move around the response values on Linux.